# How to send slash commands with selfbot in Discord using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I would like to make a script that will send a message to the disocrd channel so that (in my case) a game board is created. That is, normally when the user types /minesweeper and clicks enter, it will start working, but I made a simple script using discord.js-selfbot-v13
and it will send a message to the discord channel, but it won't trigger that command with a slash /.

```
const client = new Client()
    const channelId = '1211807309307580430'

    client.on('ready', async () => {
        console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`)

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        if (channel) {
            channel.send('/minesweeper')
        } else {
            console.error('ERROR')
        }
    })

    client.login(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a script that sends a message to a Discord channel triggering a command using a slash /, you would typically need to use a Discord bot with a library such as discord.js. Self-bots are against Discord's terms of service and should not be used.

Install discord.js:

```
npm install discord.js
```

Create a JavaScript file (e.g., bot.js) and add the following code to it:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const PREFIX = '/';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'minesweeper') {
        // Your code to create the game board here
        message.channel.send('Minesweeper game board goes here...');
    }
});
```

Replace 'YOUR_TOKEN' with your bot token

```
client.login('YOUR_TOKEN');
```

Replace 'YOUR_TOKEN' with the token of your Discord bot. You can get this token by creating a bot application on the Discord Developer Portal (https://discord.com/developers/applications) and then adding it to your server.

Run your bot script:

```
node bot.js
```

Now, when a user sends a message starting with /minesweeper in a channel where your bot is present, it will trigger the command and send a message back to the channel with the Minesweeper game board (or any other action you define in the command).

Comment: But I want to do it on a server not my own, where I don't have access to bots, will it work?

Comment: @opop you have administrative access or the ability to add bots?

Comment: I don't have :(

Comment: Than first take that administrative access

Comment: friend, I asked for help in skrpt using selfbot, I know it is incompatible with discord tos

Comment: Given that what you are wanting to do is against Discord's TOS, I wouldn't expect that you'll find much willingness to help you break said TOS here.

Comment: I guess, but hope dies last, thanks for wanting to help, but that's not what I was specifically asking about